# I'm looking for a visual composer / builder plugin that supports RTL

Tags: plugins, translation

i'm looking for a plugin that enables building pages in a visual drag & rop interface, these plugins are getting better and gaining popularity - there's several plugins in this category such as wp-bakery's "visual composer" plugin (available on codecanyon)

Now, i need this plugin for a hebrew website and "visual composer" does not support that.

Does anyone here know of some plugin that DOES support RTL and can be used as a substitute?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Hebrew version of Visual composer http://visualeditor.co.il/ which obviously supports RTL.

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot... this looks like the exact translation of wpbakery's code. Looks overpriced imho.

Comment: Hi @Bainternet  can you check why the link above is not working?  Thanks

Comment: @gilhamer sorry but this answer is over 2 years old ...

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an RTL support for that elsewhere?  thanks